# communicate CustomActionBar with TimePicker and Parent Component(DatePicker) MUI + react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datepicker, react-hook-form

I have a design where datepicker modal shows 1.date calendar, 2.time[used TimePicker mui], and 3.Actions[Cancel & Save]. To achieve that, I have used/customized CustomActionBar component[via slots/slotProps] for Actions[cancel/save] and included TimePicker component in it.
Here, I have the expected design. Now, **I need to send the selected time from CustomActionBar comp to parent comp[DatePicker]**. I am unable to find a way to send that.

Using react-hook-form to host the Datepicker & other fields.

please share your thoughts or any other feasible approach.